# How test event html in jasmine angular

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I have some functions here in my project, but I decided to choose this one as an example. My function I want to test is this.

```
   <mat-select
      *ngIf="name != '' && formControl == undefined"
      [placeholder]="placeholder"
      [formControlName]="name"
      [multiple]="multiple"
      (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)"
   >
   selectionChange = (event) => {
      let emit: any[] = [];
      if (this.multiple) {
         emit = this.selectOptions.filter((item) => {
            return event.value.find((item2) => item2 === item.value);
         });
      } else {
         emit = [this.selectOptions.find((item) => item.value === event.value)];
      }
      this.onSelectionChange.emit(emit.map((item) => item.original));
   };
```

And the function in jasmine using spies is like this, I wanted to call the selectionChange function passing the event as a parameter, but without success

```
  it('deverá chamar a função selectionChange', () => {
      
    let select = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.mat-select')).nativeElement;
   
    fixture.detectChanges();

    spyOn(component,'selectionChange').and.callThrough();
    component.selectionChange(select.event);
    expect(component.selectionChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can take advantage of `triggerEventHandler` on the `DebugElement`.

Try this:

```
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
it('deverá chamar a função selectionChange', () => {
  let select = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-select'));
  const selectSpy = spyOn(component, 'selectionChange').and.callThrough();
  // the first argument is the event you want to trigger,
  // the 2nd argument is the object that is emitted ($event)
  // mock $event however you wish
  select.triggerEventHandler('selectionChange', { value: [] });
  expect(selectSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```